# How to run docker compose up for production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

Using docker repository to install rails app on digitalocean Ubuntu 18.

I have using that app official [How to install FarmBot Web API on a Fresh Ubuntu 18.10 Machine](https://github.com/FarmBot/Farmbot-Web-App/blob/master/ubuntu_example.sh)

I have done all setup .env file, gems installation, db creation, migrations , assets precompile also.

Issue I face is that as per documentation to run app that is the command

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

but it not runs on production. How I can run in on production that when I hit ip address app runs

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "it not runs on production"?

If you just want to keep it running even after closing your terminal you would need to run it with the `-d` option like so:

```sh
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

If that is not what you are asking for please clarify.

The [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) may also be helpful.

Comment: i mean when I do sudo docker-compose up -d it should run my app at public ip address... instead of it runs on 127.0.01

Comment: That's likely not due to docker, are you using a firewall? If so did you add the port you want forwarded to its configuration?